# pickle.load() is giving error "initialization string is too small"

Tags: python, pickle

I have dumped an object(let's say variable/data structure) using pickle in python.
For dumping I am doing aas follows:

```
import pickle
filename ="query2AGI.pkl"
outfile = open(filename,'wb')
pickle.dump(AGI_Dump,outfile)
outfile.close()
```

It is basically a list of list.
When I try to load the dumped pickle file I get this error

```
      2 filename ="query2AGI.pkl"
      3 inpfile = open(filename,'rb')
----> 4 data = pickle.load(inpfile)
      5 inpfile.close()

ValueError: initialization string is too small
```

Can someone who has solved this error help me with this??
And also if you can tell me the reason of this error
Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Which version of python and pickle are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't `open(filename,'wb')` be `open(filename,'rb')`? I am sorry, I havent worked with pickle but I assume it is going to read from the file.

Comment: Are you using numpy MultiArray? The error comes from there.

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava I am using Python 3.6.8

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst The data I am dumping is a list
print(type(AGI_Dump))
--- <class 'list'>

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava pickle version 4.0

Comment: Working perfectly fine for me. Try using other approaches to save python variables.

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava
the dump is in this format:

[['what happens if enough people vote for a 3rd party candidate in the election', [0.281927437, 0.07089016, 0.0418733843, -0.763849258, 0.09274596, 0.339498162, -0.0241697878, 0.0874905139, 0.219333813, 0.155205309, 0.5380223, 0.181728318, -0.5787337, -0.109777234, -0.6417671, -0.0219474882, -0.7224677, 0.225431666, 0.542678833, 0.8190061, 0.278844029, 0.2389939, -0.360776573, 0.5964978, 0.372065663, -0.529429436, 0.4227556, 0.859029531, 0.7432822, -0.6936384, -0.04361053, 0.436934859], '0']]
What other approaches do we have??

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-d53a71ce2bc6> in <module>
      2 filename ="query2AGI.pkl"
      3 inpfile = open(filename,'rb')
----> 4 data = pickle.load(inpfile)
      5 inpfile.close()
      6 # data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,14]

ValueError: initialization string is too small